# Unable to query the table details in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am simply trying to query all details present in `Users` table:

```
select * from Users;
```

but it says table `Users` doesn't exist:

```
ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Users;

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "users" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

I might be committing a silly mistake.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had given screenshot to get the hierarchy(table creation under DB's) verified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Bare" identifiers in PostgreSQL are lowercased. So `Users` is treated as `users` (look at the error message; it mentiones `users`).

To get it to work, put the identifier in double quotes like `SELECT * from "Users";`.

If your identifiers are all lowercase already, and aren't reserved words, then you can use them bare, otherwise quote them with double quotes.

This applies to identifiers (so table names, column names, schema names, and a few other things).

Comment: Awesome catch bro !!! That was the issue. Never faced this issue in lower versions(8.x)

Comment: One more fix. I am getting result when giving select * from "Users" ; in sql editor. But I need to send this query from a java class. Any idea how I can construct a string so that it will be equal to select * from "Users". Am unable to explicitly add "" to Users, and its saying unable to find users

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough Java but it sounds straightforward. Ask a question tagged with Java.

Comment: @Ajj: Quotation marks within a Java string need to be escaped; use \" within the string. So `"SELECT * FROM \"Users\";"`.